# Sorting even numbers from original array

Tags: java, arrays

I have to create a program that reads an arbitrary number of positive integers from the user and store them into an array. The number of input data is not more than 100. After the user finishes the program should remove all even integers and place them in another array leaving all odd integers in the original array with no holes. ***It should display the contents in the original array as the order of input, the contents of the even integer array with a count, and the contents of the original array after taking out all even integers with a count***

No third array should be used

Im having trouble displaying the original array and original integer array after taking out the even integers. here is my code so far

```
import java.util.*;

public class Arrays
{

public static void main(String[] args)
{
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("Enter in any amount of positive numbers, Enter -1 when finished");

    int i=0;
    int nextElm=0;
    int a,b;

    int[] origArray = new int[100]; /* Two arrays at length 100*/
    int[] evenArray = new int[100];

    while((i<origArray.length && i<evenArray.length)&& nextElm!= -1)
    {
        System.out.println("Enter next number: ");
        nextElm = scan.nextInt();

        if (nextElm%2 != 0)//Sorts even numbers
        {
            origArray[i]= nextElm;
        }
        else
            evenArray[i] = nextElm;
            i++;

    }



    System.out.print("\n");

    System.out.println("Even Array: ");

    for (b=0; b<evenArray.length;b++)
    {
        if (evenArray[b]== -1)
        {
            evenArray[b]= 0;
        }
        if(evenArray[b]!= 0)
        {
            System.out.print(evenArray[b]+" ");
        }
    }

    System.out.print("\n");
    System.out.println("Original Array: ");

            for(a=0; a<origArray.length && a<evenArray.length; a++)
            {
                if (origArray[a]== -1)
                {
                    origArray[a]= 0;
                }
                if(origArray[a]!= 0)
                {
                    System.out.print(origArray[a]+" " + evenArray[a]);
                }
    }


    System.out.print("\n");

}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter in any amount of positive numbers, Enter -1 when finished");

    int i = 0;
    int nextElm = 0;
    int a, b;

    int[] origArray = new int[100]; /* Two arrays at length 100 */
    int[] evenArray = new int[100];

    while (nextElm != -1) {
        System.out.println("Enter next number: ");
        nextElm = scan.nextInt();
        if (nextElm > 0) {
            origArray[i] = nextElm;
            i++;
        }

    }

    int x = 0;

    System.out.println();

    // Displays original array and sorts even numbers to even array +
    // original count
    System.out.printf("\nTotal count of original array is : %d", i);
    System.out.println();
    for (int orgNumber : origArray) {
        if (orgNumber != 0) {
            System.out.print(orgNumber + " ");
        }
        if (orgNumber % 2 == 0) {
            if (orgNumber != 0) {
                evenArray[x] = orgNumber;
                x++;
            }
        }
    }

    System.out.println();

    // Displays sort even numbers to even array + even count
    System.out.printf("\nTotal count of even array is : %d", x);
    System.out.println();
    for (int evenNumber : evenArray) {
        if (evenNumber != 0) {
            System.out.print(evenNumber + " ");
        }
    }

    // Displays sort odd numbers from original array + odd count
    System.out.printf("\nTotal count of orignal array without even is : %d", i - x);
    System.out.println();
    for (int oddNumber : origArray) {
        if (oddNumber % 2 != 0) {
            System.out.print(oddNumber + " ");
        }
    }

}
```

This should work perfectly if I understood your question well. Hope you find this helpful.

Answer (score 0):

You want three separate loops. One for inputting the values (I would suggest the `while` construct as you have done) and one for sorting the values.

Your input loop should read in a new number each time and only quit when the user wants to. For example, if the user inputs a negative number, then your loop will quit. Like this:

```
System.out.println("Enter any number of numbers; enter a negative when finished.");
int nextElm = 0;
int count = 0;
while (nextElm >= 0) {
    nextElm = scan.nextInt();
    origArray[count] = nextElm;
    count++;
}
// This is where you would put a print statement that prints the original array with a count.
```

Now after this, use the [`java.util.Arrays.copyOf()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#copyOf-int:A-int-) method to trim out the empty elements of the array, like so:

```
origArray = java.util.Arrays.copyOf(origArray, count+1);
```

Next, use a `for` loop to iterate through the array, and move even numbers to the other array. This is the tricky part, because removing items from an array requires iteration to move each value to it's previous index.

```
int j = 0;
for (int i=0; i<count; i++){
    if (origArray[i] % 2 == 0){
        evenArray[j] = origArray[i]; //add even number to evenArray
        j++;                         //move to next index of evenArray
        for (int k=i; k<(origArray.length-1); k++){
            origArray[k] = origArray[k+1]; //store next value in current index
        }
    }
}
```

Then finally, use the [`java.util.Arrays.copyOf()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#copyOf-int:A-int-) method to trim out the empty elements of the array again, like so:

```
evenArray = java.util.Arrays.copyOf(evenArray, j+1);
```

---

<sub>Disclaimer: This was all coded from the hip so let me know if I missed something or did something incorrectly.</sub>